# what is the place of these 2 words "known" and "preserved" in the following sentence?

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

what is the place of these 2 words "known" and "preserved" in the following sentence?

> The Chauvet-Pont-d'Arc Cave in the Ardèche department of southern France is a cave that contains the earliest **known** and best **preserved** figurative cave paintings in the world,[1] as well as other evidence of Upper Paleolithic life.

Verb or adjective or noun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're past participles acting as attributive adjectives (or 'Adnominals', if you want to distinguish the syntactic function from the word class) modifying *figurative cave paintings*.